# How to enable mbstring in cpanel without easyapache

Tags: cpanel

How to enable mbstring in cpanel for PHP 7 
without ssh access. 
I need an alternative solution to enable mbstring

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are two packages, that provide the `mbstring` extension for php:

- `php7.1-mbstring`
- `php-mbstring`

Install one of them with the package manager from your distribution (e.g. `apt install [package]`).

Comment: No ssh access for me then how can I enable it